# How are subtype and parametric polymorphism combined together?

Tags: polymorphism, programming-languages, computer-science

From [Programming Language Pragmatics](https://books.google.com/books?id=jM-cBAAAQBAJ&lpg=PA302&ots=ysB1i-Pul0&dq=The%20combination%20of%20subtype%20and%20parametric%20polymorphism**%20is%20particularly%20useful%20for%20container%20(collection)%20classes%20such%20as&pg=PA302#v=onepage&q=The%20combination%20of%20subtype%20and%20parametric%20polymorphism**%20is%20particularly%20useful%20for%20container%20(collection)%20classes%20such%20as&f=false), by Scott

> **The combination of subtype and parametric polymorphism** is particularly useful for container (collection) classes such as “list
>   of T” (List) or “stack of T” (Stack), where T is initially
>   unspeciﬁed, and can be instantiated later as almost any type.

Where is subtype polymorphism is used in container classes?  I thought it would be putting constraint on type parameter `T` so that `T` is any subtype of a given type, but it says that "T is initially unspeciﬁed". So I am confused.

Thanks.

Comment: I think the author is referring to something similar to Java PECS principle and C# co/contra-variance. For example, in Java `Function<Animal, Cat>` can be assigned to `Function<? super Mammal, ? extends Feline>` because you a function taking an animal can also handle a mammal and a function returning a cat is also returning a feline.

Answer (score 1):

As the full text states, it is describing generics where the type can be specified at run time.

> Where is subtype polymorphism is used in container classes?

A library might define a class container from which list and stack are derived.

The "parametric polymorphism" (which I think is a bad name) refers to the ability to use a generic class and create

List of Integer

List of String

etc.